# NGINX Reverse Proxy target dynamic host

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am using nginx plus and need to pass the host as header variable , if no value is passed in header the default host should be used.  Below my nginx.conf, Can anybody help me with the config

```
http {
resolver 172.10.0.10 valid=10s ipv6=off;
  upstream demo {
  zone demoservers 64k;
    server demo-server.com:443 resolve;
  }
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    location / {
      proxy_pass https://demo-server.com;
      proxy_ssl_server_name off;
    }
  }
  server {
    listen 8080;

    location /api {
    api write=off;
    # directives limiting access to the API
    }

    location = /test.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # Redirect requests made to the pre-NGINX Plus API dashboard
    location = /test1.html {
      return 301 /test.html;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map $host $destination {
host1.com 192.168.1.1;
host2.com 192.168.1.2;
default   192.168.1.254;
}
```

Then you can use it in proxy_pass

```
location / {
      proxy_pass https://$destination;
      proxy_ssl_server_name off;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @GlitchingNinja . is there a way to achieve this without keeping the host details in map block, so that I can pass any hosts in the header. Also, what will be the header for passing this dynamic hosts?

Comment: depending on how many destinations you going to use

Comment: this is going to be one destination(upstream). 
If upstream is not passed via header, default upstream server has to be picked, is there a way to achieve this without keeping the host details in map block, so that I can pass any hosts in the header.